# Convert UTC TZ Time to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.zzzzzzz in Golang

Tags: date, datetime, go, time

I'd like to take an example date string such as `"2022-11-08T15:27:41.01333333Z"` and convert it to `"2022-11-08 15:27:41.01333333"` in Golang. I essentially just want to turn the UTC date into a readable datetime2 expression for SQL Server.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main () {
    t := "2022-11-08T15:27:41.01333333Z"
    // How to Parse?
}
```

Comment: `datetime2` has no format, it's a binary value. Don't replace anything. If you want to insert a Go date to the database write a parameterized query and pass the value as a date parameter. Not as a string

Comment: `d, _ := time.Parse("2006-02-01T15:04:05", t)` https://akashmittal.com/parse-date-string-golang/

Comment: `2022-11-08T15:27:41.01333333` is **NOT UTC** either. That's a *local* time because it has no offset. UTC means an offset of `+00:00`. The `Z` suffix is also used, so `2022-11-08T15:27:41.01333333Z` is identical to ``2022-11-08T15:27:41.01333333 +00:00`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant to add the Z. My apologies. I essentially wanted to load what is provided as a UTC date (using T & Z) into a column that is aptly named UTC but in a usable format

Comment: "*How to Parse?*" -> [time package docs](https://pkg.go.dev/time), esp. [Parse](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Parse). But note @PanagiotisKanavos first comment. Conversion to and from string might be unnecessary.

Comment: @Chetan your parsing layout is wrong.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what data type (in sql) would suffice if I want to store a UTC timestamp (including T & Z) without timezone offset (e.g. omitting the + 00:00:00)?

Comment: @FObersteiner what would be the correct one then?

Comment: @Chetan see Tinkerer's answer. Check the error output to see if it works (instead of ignoring it with `_`).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := "2022-11-08T15:27:41.01333333Z"
    const layout = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.00000000Z07:00"
    x, err := time.Parse(layout, t)
    const render = "2006-01-02 15:04:05.00000000"
    fmt.Println(x.Format(render), err)
}
```