# Golang Equivalent of Python's `pd.to_datetime()`

Tags: go

I'm new to Go, and looking to create my own algo trading strategy backtesting library, an area I'm well experienced in with Python, to help learn the language.

I have a 5 minute OHLCV `SPY5min.csv` dataset, the head of which looks like this:

[image: dataset]

I use this code to read in the dataset from the file, converting everything to a list of lists of values:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "log"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

func ReadCsvFile(filePath string) [][]string {
    f, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to read input file "+filePath, err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    csvReader := csv.NewReader(f)
    records, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to parse file as CSV for "+filePath, err)
    }

    return records
}

func main() {
    records := ReadCsvFile("./SPY5min.csv")
    fmt.Println(records)
}
```

[image: importedDataset]

This returns a list of lists of string values. Cool. Now what I want to do is replicate a Pandas Dataframe like object, or perhaps separate each "column" into their own separate arrays/slices if that's easier, not sure yet.

Once that's done, I need a way to convert the strings of datetimes to actual datetime objects that I can run comparisons and `loc`'s on. Can someone point me in the right direction?

My naive approach (pseudo) would be to:

1. Declare 6 array variables (datetime, open, high, low, close, volume) of `len(records)` in size
2. Iterate over the `records` list of lists
3. Insert each value into the current `i` of their respective arrays
4. Once iteration is done, mass convert the values in the `datetime` array to values of datetime objects?

Wondering if this is really the best way of doing this, or if there's a faster way than `O(n)` iteration?

Answer (score 2):

You asked, "Once that's done, I need a way to convert the strings of datetimes to actual datetime objects ...". I recently answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74491722/5739452

Your timestamp looks like this: `"2022-11-08 4:00"`. The [`time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time) package contains parsing and other manipulation functions. The key detail is knowing the conventions for the layout parser format. Each element of a time is recognized as a specific number. The year is `2006`, the month is `01` etc.

So, for your purpose something like this should work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := "2022-11-08 4:00"
    const layout = "2006-01-02 15:04"
    x, err := time.Parse(layout, t)
    fmt.Println(x, err)
}
```

Comment: So I would still have to iterate over the array of datetime values converting them one by one? In Python, there's a `pd.to_datetime(datetime_column)` function that does it in one shot.

Comment: Yes, you will need something like that.